# TypeError: 'AttributeError: 'str' object is not callable' when using spacy to lemmatize a list of sentences

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension, spacy

I have the following code and I want to process a list of sentences and get only the same sentences but with specific word such as verb, adjectif and so on.

I getting this error "str' object is not callable
" and I was supposing the problem was because I give a string to the object "doc" but normally "doc" should take str so I do not know why I get the error.

```
import spacy, re
from spacy_lefff import LefffLemmatizer, POSTagger
from spacy.language import Language

def create_processed_dataset(texte):

    #print(type(texte)) # liste
    sent_final = []

    nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md') #disable = ["parser", "ner"]
    for s in texte:
        print(type(s))

        sent_clean = normalize(s) # remove punctuation 
        print(sent_clean)
        sent_clean=nlp(sent_clean)
        sent_processed = [word.lemma_().lower().strip() for word in sent_clean if word.pos_ == "ADJ" or word.pos_ == "NOUN" or word.pos_ == "ADV" or word.pos_ == "VERB" or word.pos_ == "ADP"]
        sent_final.append(sent_processed)

    print(sent_final)


exemple = ["Je n'ai pas de prise de courant de mon côté du lit, et je n'en aurai toujours pas. Cela ne résout pas le problème de l'ajout de bouchons.",
           "Je n'y crois pas vraiment parce que cela a un coût et pour les propriétaires qui ont déjà du mal à le mettre en route, donc dans un aspect de diagnostic complet, je pense qu'ils auraient du mal à comprendre, c'est assez technique pour le grand public. Ensuite, il y a les questions de priorités d'investissement."]

create_processed_dataset(exemple)
```

Error

```
   File "remove_noise.py", line 66, in create_processed_dataset
    sent_tokens = [token.lemma_().lower().strip() for token in sent_w if token.pos_ == "ADJ" or token.pos_ == "NOUN" or token.pos_ == "ADV" or token.pos_ == "VERB" or token.pos_ == "ADP"]
  File "remove_noise.py", line 66, in <listcomp>
    sent_tokens = [token.lemma_().lower().strip() for token in sent_w if token.pos_ == "ADJ" or token.pos_ == "NOUN" or token.pos_ == "ADV" or token.pos_ == "VERB" or token.pos_ == "ADP"]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is unclear about `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pos_'`? pos_ is not a valid attribute for strings in python.

Comment: So perhaps do you  have an idea how an I retrieve word with the specified pos" should I create a list of pos and then make an if condition.

Comment: What's the type of the latest `sent_clean` variable

Comment: @emma To specify a position in a string you just `'this is a string'[2:4]`

Comment: @Vishnudev  it is a
<class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>

Comment: Then this should have worked. Try iterating with simple for loop and debug.

Comment: You should create a different post for a different issue. Don't modify as you solve.

Comment: @It_is_Chris thank you for response but I really do not understand what you wrote, but for some strange reasons the error change and now is "str ont callable"

Comment: POS is Parts of Speech @It_is_Chris

Comment: Your answer: It should be just `token.lemma_.lower().strip()` @emma

Comment: @Vishnudev thank you indeed that was the proble I failed to see, thank you!!!